# Laravel - enabling admin to download files uploaded by multiple users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for advice, I'm trying to enable multiple users to upload files to a location and allow admin to download/view these files. I'm wondering what would be the best way to approach this. I have not been able to find much online so I'm reaching out here. If anyone could advise I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What about writing some code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, you will want to read the documentation on File Storage

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

This will explain the principles of disks and the various storage facades that are available.

If you want a way of assocaiting different files with specific users, I would suggest the `MediaLibrary` package by Spatie.

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/introduction/

Comment: No problems, Spatie provide many good packages for Laravel and work closely with the Laravel development team. There website is usually a good place to look for good quality extensions